# Use ( for VBA and [ for C# confusion

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm facing an issue to convert VB.NET To C#, to be clear here is VB.NET code :

VB. NET :

```
  Private listFlDay As New List(Of FlowLayoutPanel)
```

C# :

```
  private List<FlowLayoutPanel> listFlDay = new List<FlowLayoutPanel>();
```

So far all is well, but in my code on VBA i have this method :

VB :

```
listFlDay((i - 1) + (startDayAtFlNumber - 1)).Tag = i
```

C# :

```
 listFlDay((i - 1) + (startDayAtFlNumber - 1)).Tag = i;
```

but i have an error like : listFlDay cannot be used  as a method in C#

Can you please told me how i can convert this to C# ?

Thank you

Kamal

Comment: You don't need to put the type on both sides of the = in modern C# `private List<FlowLayoutPanel> listFlDay = new();` will be fine

Answer (score 1):

> but in my code on VBA i have this in one methode

No you don't.  `listFlDay` isn't a method.  You just declared it as a `List`.

In VB you use parentheses to invoke a method but you *also* use them to index an array, or in this case a `List`.  In C# you use square brackets to index an array (or `List`):

```
listFlDay[(i - 1) + (startDayAtFlNumber - 1)].Tag = i;
```

Comment: Well done David, Thank you for your answer :) 
Its okay Now